# Replace Add To Wishlist text with Heart icon WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi friends I am using YITH WooCommerce Wishlist plugin by default Add To Wishlist text is coming, I want to replace the Button text with icon.

is it possible through any hook?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Add To Wishlist' text you can replace navigating `Wordpress Dashboard --> YITH Plugins --> Wishlist` page.

To customize button, copy the file `plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/templates/add-to-wishlist-button.php` to `your-theme/woocommerce` directory (If haven't created yet, [create](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)) and apply your changes.

For more information see [plugin FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/faq/), also [plug-in documnetation](https://yithemes.com/docs-plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/02-settings.html).

Comment: Sorry for late reply , let me try