# Woocommerce add to wish list heart icon disappears

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have updated my WordPress version to **4.9.4** and also updated **YITH WooCommerce Wishlist** plugin now the issue is that first a heart icon was there for add to wishlist but now only text coming.

I want to change it back to that heart icon. I have also copied the `add-to-wishlist-button.php` file into my `theme/woocommerce` directory but it is not working for me.

I searched a lot but found nothing and as a last option, I am posting this question. I have also tried the following solution but it is also not working for me.
[Displaying Heart icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174732/replace-add-to-wishlist-text-with-heart-icon-woocommerce)

**EDIT:**
         Here is the code that is displaying that button.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'add_to_wishlist', $product_id ) )?>" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-product-type="<?php echo $product_type?>" class="<?php echo $link_classes ?>" >
<?php echo $icon ?>
<?php echo $label ?>
</a>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( YITH_WCWL_URL . 'assets/images/wpspin_light.gif' ) ?>" class="ajax-loading" alt="loading" width="16" height="16" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @yuri sir sorry don't mind me saying but this issue is not caused by my code I just updated some things up on my site and suddenly that icon disappear now I don't know how can I include code into this

Comment: Yes, but we can't help you if you don't provide some code, website url etc.. If you are a programmer you should be able to locate the plugin code printing the icon HTML and post here. I mean, I can't create a WP website and install that plugin in order to help you..

Comment: Sir I have updated my question with the code that is displaying that button